# Limitar o tamanho de set<> com JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Estou com uma dificuldade já busquei no Google e não encontrei uma solução.

Tenho uma anotação em **JPA** com um `set<>` quero limitar o tamanho de objetos dentro do `set`, ou seja, o código abaixo:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "pidAplic", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@OrderBy("data DESC")
@JsonManagedReference
private Set<ExecAplic> execucoes;
```

Ele trás uma `List` com varios objetos quero limitar o tamanho para **30**.

Answer (score 1):

Nativamente ainda não existe uma solução para isso.

Se você estiver utilizando o Session do Hibernate tente utilizar a anoção @Size ou @BatchSize:

```
@OneToMany(...)
@Size(min=1, max=30)
private List<Carro> carroList;
```

ou

```
@OneToMany(...)
@BatchSize(size=30)
private List<Carro> carroList;
```

Comment: Olá uaiHebert já tentei o size e o BatchSize e ambos não funcionaram

Comment: Mas você está utilizando o session?

Comment: estou utilizando o session do hibernate

Comment: E com o size? funcionou?

Comment: não, eu fiz um for para tratar os resultados